# .htaccess does not change the value but adds

Tags: html, forms, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

My html radio type form with GET method adds value to url, but it must change this value.
I started live preview in which you can watch this. I think problem is in .htaccess. What I should do? Help pls.

---

First click on menu option: /user/history
Second click on another option: /user/history/settings
But it must change from this: /user/history

---

My html menu looks like this:

```
<script>
  function autoSubmit(){
    var formObject=document.forms['page'];
    formObject.submit();}
</script>

<form name='page' id='page'>
    <input id="history" type="radio" name="page" onChange="autoSubmit();" value="history">
    <label for="history">History</label>

    <input id="settings" type="radio" name="page" onChange="autoSubmit();" value="settings">
    <label for="settings">Settings</label>
<form>
```

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.*)/?\?page=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [QSD,R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ user.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My code:

```
<script>
  function autoSubmit(){
    var formObject=document.forms['page'];
    formObject.submit();}
</script>
<?php
$p="";
if(isset($_GET["page"])){$p=$_GET["page"];
}
?>

<form name='page' id='page'>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <input id="history" type="radio" name="page" <?php if ($p == 'history') { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?> onChange="autoSubmit();" value="history" >
        <label class="list-group-item" for="history">History</label>
        <input id="transaction" type="radio" name="page" <?php if ($p == 'transaction') { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?>onChange="autoSubmit();" value="transaction">
        <label class="list-group-item" for="transaction">Transactions</label>
        <input id="settings" type="radio" name="page" <?php if ($p == 'settings') { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?>onChange="autoSubmit();" value="settings">
        <label class="list-group-item" for="settings">Settings</label>
    </ul>
</form>
<style>
.list-group input[type=radio]{display:none;}
.list-group{color:#3167eb;}
.list-group input[type=radio]:checked+label
{background:#3167eb;color:#fff;}
</style>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a back-end language or stack instead? .htaccess for for configuring apache.

Comment: @ShannonA so it is possible, but I do not understand it

Comment: The back-end would use something like PHP, Node.js, Django, and so on. I will give you two resources:
Learn what .htaccess is: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/
And Back-end dev: https://sagaratechnology.medium.com/what-languages-are-used-for-back-end-development-71a8a10c135c

Comment: I assume you are using PHP, would you like to me to give an example?

Comment: I edit my post by adding a part of code

Comment: Ah, the problems we would not have in the first place, if we did not try to _abuse_ a form as navigation, right? :-) Seriously, why are you doing that, instead of using a handful of normal links? // As for the problem itself, with your rewrite you are changing the base _path_ that all relative URLs will be resolved against, more specifically the path _depth_. Probably easily fixable, if you explicitly specified the `action` of your form, instead of letting it fall back to the current URL.